# Python 3 TCP/IP ascii command

Tags: python, tcp, python-3.x, ip

I am trying to send an ascii command to my stepper drive (RV which is the move command).
but everything that I have tried ends up with Python (I think) adding an extra character to the beginning of the "string"; in this case it added a "g". The stepper command terminal does not add the "g".

**From Wireshark**:

```
0000  00 04 a3 22 56 6e f0 1f  af 0b ba fd 08 00 45 00   ..."Vn.. ......E.
0010  00 20 35 b5 00 00 80 11  00 00 c0 a8 4b 62 c0 a8   . 5..... ....Kb..
0020  4b 96 d6 a3 1e 5f 00 0c  18 67 52 56 0a 20         K...._.. .gRV.
```

**Python**:

```
def main():
    import socket

    data1 = bytes('RV\n ', 'ascii')
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("108.108.108.150",7775))
    s.send(data1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried `s.send('RV\n')` rather than using `bytes()`? What version of Python are you using (`bytes` doesn't work the way you're using it for me)?

Comment: I very much doubt that the 0x67 byte (ASCII 'g') is coming from Python. Try `s.send('')` and I think you'll see the same packet in Wireshark, with just the last four bytes (the `'RV\n '` bytes) removed. There are no errors in your code that I could see; everything looks correct.

Comment: I am using pyhton 3.3. Just doing a s.send('') it doesn't work so I did a:  data1 = bytes('', 'ascii') which should be the same??? Anyways, I get a cRV

Comment: I also tried b"RV" and i get an eRV. What am I missing? Where is the leading character or header coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You should never make an assumption on any 'printable' strings in packets, unless you know the meaning of every byte.
In this particular case, bytes '.g', or 0x18 0x67 are UDP checksum. AFAIK, it can be disabled somehow. If your receiver will get this packet, it will have 52 56 0a 20 ("RV\n ") in its data field.
 Thats why you always get 'cRV' or 'eRV' by slightly changing payload and [maybe] udp source port.