# Python 3.3 adding header to ascii string

Tags: python, tcp, ascii, python-3.3

I'm trying to send an ascii command over tcp/ip but python (i think) add a header to he string.

if I do a `s.send(bytes('RV\n ', 'ascii'))` I get an eRV rather than RV when I inspect the command going out. Any ideas?

[Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968253/python-3-tcp-ip-ascii-command).

Answer (score 0):

**receiver**

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.bind(('', 7775))
>>> print(s.recvfrom(1024))
(b'RV\n', ('127.0.0.1', 39860))
```

**sender**

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.connect(('localhost', 7775))
>>> s.send(bytes('RV\n', 'ascii'))
3
```

Check return value of send(). It should be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Could you include the wireshark details again?  The packet in the previous post didn't match your code ... for example, the IP addresses are 192.168.75.98 and 192.168.75.150 in the byte dump.  The problem is that the byte offsets don't match reality.  I think that the `e` is end of the TCP header.